# Why does Illustrator mangle group/id names in generated SVG files?

Tags: xml, svg, adobe-illustrator

i need your support for svg file to xml conversion 
example

[image]

THIS IMAGE IS SVG FILE created with group name with auto A/C

NOW xml  CODE

```
<g id="With_auto_A_x2F_C">
        <text transform="matrix(0.9965 0 0 1 447.8486 12.79)" fill="#13110C" font-family="'Helvetica'" font-size="5.9999">With auto A/C</text>
    </g>
</g>
```

why for group name g id is creating like "With_auto_A_x2F_C"> for special characters like "/" changed to x2F and " " characters changed to "_" why 
can anybody help me to solve this issue.

also can you provide me all special characters conversion for xml code.

Thanks,
Yogesh.v

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was mentioned if you save file in SVG format, object and layer names must conform to XML naming conventions. How illustrator converts this names you can see right away in Layer Panel, for this open **Edit->Preferences->Units** and set **'Identify Objects'** to **'XML ID'**.

Comment: In javascript, you can decode them with this: `input.replace(/_x([0-9A-Za-z]+)_/g, s => String.fromCodePoint(parseInt(s.substring(2, s.length - 1), 16))).replace(/_/g, " ");`

Answer (score 3):

It is converting the name because not all characters are allowed in `id` attributes.

This list of valid characters for `id` attributes [can be found in the XML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-Name), but basically it includes:

- ASCII letters and digits
- `:`, `_`, `-`, and `.`
- some other unicode characters

As for what the exact algorithm Illustrator uses to filter text strings to make ids - I don't know.  You'll have to experiment. However it looks like it converts whitespace to underscore ('_'). And it escapes other incompatible characters by converting them to hexadecimal.  2F is the value in hexadecimal of the ASCII code for the slash character ('/').  So it looks like it escapes by surrounding that with `_x` and `_`.

So for example, the plus sign ('+'), whose hex value is 2B is probably going to be escaped as `_x2B_`.